# Raw sockets in Haskell

Tags: sockets, unix, networking, haskell

There is a raw socket type provided in Network.Socket, but near binding sockets there is a comment "Currently only Unix domain sockets and the Internet families are supported". How can I use raw sockets in haskell?

What I am trying to achieve, as working Python code:

```
import binascii
import socket

# Create raw socket.
ethType = b'FFFF' # 2 bytes, has to be >= 0x0600. FFFF is "unavailable" by IEEE.
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW)
sock.bind( ('lo', int(ethType,16)) )

# Create packet.
srcMac  = b'000000000000' # 6 bytes
destMac = b'000000000000' # 6 bytes
header = binascii.a2b_hex( destMac + srcMac + ethType ) # 14 bytes
message = b'Hello, World!'
sock.send(header + message)

# Receive such packets
while True: print (sock.recv(65535))
```

EDIT1:
In Haskell, I use `sock <- socket AF_PACKET Raw 0xFFFF` to create a socket, but `bindSocket` requires a `SockAddr` as an argument, for which available constructors are

```
SockAddrInet PortNumber HostAddress  
SockAddrInet6 PortNumber FlowInfo HostAddress6 ScopeID   
SockAddrUnix String
```

but none of these seems right.

EDIT2:
Thanks to a comment by Yuras I got receiving packets to work:

```
import Network.Socket
sock <- socket AF_PACKET Raw 0xFFFF
recv sock 0xFFFF
```

EDIT3:
Trying to send a packet from a socket without binding it results in an exception:

```
sock <- socket AF_PACKET Raw 0xFFFF
send sock "\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\255\255"
*** Exception: send: does not exist (No such device or address)
```

This makes sense, because the kernel would not have any clue on which interface to actually transmit the packet. Is there any way to bind a (raw) socket to an interface in Haskell?

Comment: ...what's your question?

Comment: [`AF_PACKET`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/network/2.3.0.11/doc/html/src/Network-Socket-Internal.html#Family)` is supported, as is [`SOCK_RAW`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/network/2.3.0.11/doc/html/src/Network-Socket.html#SocketType). Looks like a straight forward translation to me.

Comment: I have managed to create a socket, but what to bind it to? How?

Comment: I suggest you to add the Haskell code you wrote so far to the question, or you'll have trouble obtaining specific answers. Also point out better which is the problem with your translation.

Comment: Use [`bindSocket`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/network/2.3.0.11/doc/html/Network-Socket.html#v:connect).

Comment: Added more details. Good to know that I'm looking at the right module.

Comment: I can't find `socket.AF_PACKET` anywhere on [the Python docs for the socket library](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html). I'd take a wild guess and assume that since you are giving it a `String` and an `Int`, that Haskell's `SockAddrInet` would work.

Comment: AF_PACKET is an int. But SockAddrInet takes a `PortNumber = PortNum Word16` and a `type HostAddress = Word32`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Network.Pcap](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pcap/0.4.5.1/doc/html/Network-Pcap.html#t%3aCallbackBS) can be used to send and receive raw data.

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import Network.Pcap

main = do
    -- open device
    dev <- openLive "lo" 65535 False 0
    setFilter dev "ether proto 0xFFFF" True 0

    -- send
    sendPacketBS dev (B.pack "\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\255\255Hello, World!")

    -- receive
    loopBS dev (-1) (\_ packet -> putStrLn (show packet))
```

Answer (score 1):

This interface is supported by [Network.Socket](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/network/2.3.0.11/doc/html/Network-Socket.html).

Comment: Actually, it is not. I believe `Network.Socket` does not know anything about `struct sockaddr_ll` that's required for binding `AF_PACKET` sockets. Only addresses of Inet, Inet6 and Unix flavours are supported.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to bind raw socket to use it. From `man 7 raw`

> A  raw  socket can be bound to a specific local address using the bind(2) call.  If it isn't bound, all packets with the specified IP protocol are received.

If you want to bind it, then you can use `bindSocket` because raw sockets use the same `sockaddr` structure as `ip` uses:

> Raw sockets use the standard sockaddr_in address structure defined in ip(7)

Comment: Why is it so that I can receive without binding the socket, but cannot send (tried with the Python code above, got ` [Errno 6] No such device or address`)?

Comment: @Andres that error message sounds like you are sending to an invalid location.

Comment: To send data OS at least need to decide what interface (e.g. `lo` or `eth0`) it should use. So you need to bind to address or bind to device using `SO_BINDTODEVICE` socket option. AFAIK the last one is not supported by `network` package

Comment: @Yuras As far as I see I can use sockaddr_in with raw sockets if I'm using them for IP, but otherwise it seems just pointless. "struct sockaddr_in is the structure used with IPv4 addresses" from "Beej's Guide to Network Programming". I doubt sending to an invalid location is the problem as after binding the socket I can send from mac 0 to mac 0 and it still gets transmitted.

Comment: @Yuras from man 7 socket, SO_BINDTODEVICE: "Note that this only works for some socket types, particularly AF_INET sockets. It is *not supported for packet sockets* (use normal bind(2) there)."

Comment: `man 7 raw` suggested that `SO_BINDTODEVICE` can be used for raw sockets. I never tried it myself, and docs can be wrong...

Comment: Actually, OP was using `AF_PACKET` not `AF_INET`, so `struct sockaddr_in` is pointless, and `struct sockaddr_ll` must be used instead. AFAIK, it is not supported by current `network` (2.4.0.1), so it seems that FFI (like `Network.Pcap` does) is an only viable option.

Answer (score 1):

Had similar task and the only way I could come with is using [FFI](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/FFI_Introduction). Current `network` (2.4.0.1 at the time of writing) only knows about three [`SockAddr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/network/2.4.0.1/doc/html/Network-Socket.html#t%3aSockAddr) families, none of which are suitable for `AF_PACKET` sockets. What's required is `struct sockaddr_ll`, which is not available.

There was a [patch that added `SockAddrRaw`](https://github.com/haskell/network/pull/11), but even though it was merget it seems that it was eventually lost.

My code is dirty (sorry, that's my first "serious" FFI code ever), but I thought I'd share it anyway.

First, I created `BindPacketHack.hsc`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP, ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

module BindPacketHack (bindPacket) where

import Foreign
import Foreign.C.Types
import Foreign.C.String
import Network.Socket
import Network.Socket.Internal (zeroMemory)

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netpacket/packet.h>
#include <net/if.h>

data SockAddrLL = SockAddrLL { family :: CShort
                             , protocol :: CShort
                             , ifindex :: CInt }
   deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Storable SockAddrLL where
    sizeOf _    = (#size struct sockaddr_ll)
    alignment _ = alignment (undefined :: CInt)
    peek _      = error "peek is not implemented, sorry"
    poke ptr sa = do
        zeroMemory ptr (fromIntegral $ sizeOf sa)
        (#poke struct sockaddr_ll, sll_family) ptr (family sa)
        (#poke struct sockaddr_ll, sll_protocol) ptr (protocol sa)
        (#poke struct sockaddr_ll, sll_ifindex) ptr (ifindex sa)


foreign import ccall unsafe "if_nametoindex"
    c_if_nametoindex :: CString -> IO CInt

ifaceIndex :: String -> IO CInt
ifaceIndex name = withCString name c_if_nametoindex


foreign import ccall unsafe "bind"
    c_bind_ll :: CInt -> Ptr SockAddrLL -> CInt -> IO CInt

bindLL :: Socket -> SockAddrLL -> IO Integer
bindLL s sa = alloca $ \ptr -> do
    poke ptr sa
    ret <- c_bind_ll (fdSocket s) ptr (fromIntegral $ sizeOf sa)
    return $ toInteger ret


bindPacket :: Socket -> ProtocolNumber -> String -> IO ()
bindPacket s proto ifname = do
    ifindex <- ifaceIndex ifname
    bindLL s (sockAddrLL (fromIntegral proto) ifindex)
    return ()
```

As you might notice, the `SockAddrLL` is incomplete and thus my implementation is quite limited. This is because I've needed only those three fields, with the rest being zeroed out. Adding more is trivial, though.

Run `hsc2hs BindPacketHack.hsc`, it'll parse C header files and a `.hs` file will appear. Now you can use it like this:

```
s <- socket AF_PACKET Raw eth_PPPoEDiscovery
setFdOption (Fd $ fdSocket s) CloseOnExec True
setSocketOption s Broadcast 1
bindPacket s eth_PPPoEDiscovery "eth0"
send s rawPPPoEPacket -- don't forget Ethernet header
```